# Lookup in mongo DB

Tags: python, mongodb

I am trying to model a database for a custom blog website using mongoDB. I have following collections

User collection :

```
[{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "5ed15463f43c335cb2e9ef73"
  },
  "first_name": "xxx1",
  "last_name": "xxx1",
  "email": "xxx@gmail.com"
},{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "5ed15463f43c335cb2e9ef74"
  },
  "first_name": "xxx2",
  "last_name": "xxx2",
  "email": "xxx2@gmail.com"
},{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "5ed15463f43c335cb2e9ef75"
  },
  "first_name": "xxx3",
  "last_name": "xxx3",
  "email": "xxx3@gmail.com"
},{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "5ed15463f43c335cb2e9ef76"
  },
  "first_name": "xxx4",
  "last_name": "xxx4",
  "email": "xxx4@gmail.com"
},{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "5ed15463f43c335cb2e9ef77"
  },
  "first_name": "xxx3",
  "last_name": "xxx3",
  "email": "xxx3@gmail.com"
},{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "5ed15463f43c335cb2e9ef78"
  },
  "first_name": "xxx4",
  "last_name": "xxx4",
  "email": "xxx4@gmail.com"
}]
```

Post collection: I have created embeded document called Comments and likes and used reference field of user_id from User collection.

```
[{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "5f232c18a93ce29203b3f2f6"
  },
  "post_created_user_id": {
    "$oid": "5ed15463f43c335cb2e9ef73"
  },
  "post_date": {
    "$date": "2020-07-30T20:22:48.839Z"
  },
  "post_content": "Content 1",
  "post_likes": [
    {
      "user_id": {
        "$oid": "5ed15463f43c335cb2e9ef75"
      }
    },
    {
      "user_id": {
        "$oid": "5ed15463f43c335cb2e9ef76"
      }
    }
  ],
  "post_comments": [
    {
      "comment_id": {
        "$oid": "5f2850966efb9d4e803b2030"
      },
      "user_id": {
        "$oid": "5ed15463f43c335cb2e9ef73"
      },
      "comment_content": "Test comment1",
      "comment_date": {
        "$date": "2020-08-03T17:59:50.132Z"
      }
    },
    {
      "comment_id": {
        "$oid": "5f2850ff6efb9d4e803b2033"
      },
      "user_id": {
        "$oid": "5ed15463f43c335cb2e9ef74"
      },
      "comment_content": "test comments 1",
      "comment_date": {
        "$date": "2020-08-03T18:01:35.008Z"
      }
    }
  ]
},{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "5f232c18a93ce29203b3f2f7"
  },
  "post_created_user_id": {
    "$oid": "5ed15463f43c335cb2e9ef73"
  },
  "post_date": {
    "$date": "2020-07-30T20:22:48.839Z"
  },
  "post_content": "content 2",
  "post_likes": [
    {
      "user_id": {
        "$oid": "5ed15463f43c335cb2e9ef77"
      }
    },
    {
      "user_id": {
        "$oid": "5ed15463f43c335cb2e9ef78"
      }
    }
  ],
  "post_comments": [
    {
      "comment_id": {
        "$oid": "5f2850966efb9d4e803b2030"
      },
      "user_id": {
        "$oid": "5ed15463f43c335cb2e9ef73"
      },
      "comment_content": "Test comment1",
      "comment_date": {
        "$date": "2020-08-03T17:59:50.132Z"
      }
    },
    {
      "comment_id": {
        "$oid": "5f2850ff6efb9d4e803b2033"
      },
      "user_id": {
        "$oid": "5ed15463f43c335cb2e9ef74"
      },
      "comment_content": "test comments 1",
      "comment_date": {
        "$date": "2020-08-03T18:01:35.008Z"
      }
    }
  ]
}]
```

Desire output :

```
 {
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5f232c18a93ce29203b3f2f6"
    },
    "post_created_user_id": {
        "$oid": "5ed15463f43c335cb2e9ef73"
    },
    "post_date": {
        "$date": "2020-07-30T20:22:48.839Z"
    },
    "post_content": "Content 1",
      "post_likes": [{
        "user_id": {
            "$oid": "5ed15463f43c335cb2e9ef73"
        },
        user_info : {
            "first_name": "xxx1",
            "last_name": "xxx1",
            "email": "xxx@gmail.com"
        
    }, {
        "user_id": {
            "$oid": "5ed15463f43c335cb2e9ef74"
        },
        user_info : {
            "first_name": "xxx2",
            "last_name": "xxx2",
            "email": "xxx2@gmail.com"
        
    }],
    "post_comments": [{
        "comment_id": {
            "$oid": "5f2850966efb9d4e803b2030"
        },
        "user_id": {
            "$oid": "5ed15463f43c335cb2e9ef73"
        },
        "comment_content": "Test comment1",
        "comment_date": {
            "$date": "2020-08-03T17:59:50.132Z"
        },
        user_info : {
            "first_name": "xxx1",
            "last_name": "xxx1",
            "email": "xxx@gmail.com"
        }
    }, {
        "comment_id": {
            "$oid": "5f2850ff6efb9d4e803b2033"
        },
        "user_id": {
            "$oid": "5ed15483f43c335cb2e9ef74"
        },
        "comment_content": "test comments 1",
        "comment_date": {
            "$date": "2020-08-03T18:01:35.008Z"
        }
        user_info : {
            "first_name": "xxx2",
            "last_name": "xxx2",
            "email": "xxx2@gmail.com"
        }
    }]
}
```

Look up I tried on Post collection:

```
[
    {
        '$unwind': {
            'path': '$post_likes', 
            'preserveNullAndEmptyArrays': True
        }
    }, {
        '$unwind': {
            'path': '$post_comments', 
            'preserveNullAndEmptyArrays': True
        }
    }, {
        '$lookup': {
            'from': 'users_details', 
            'localField': 'post_likes.user_id', 
            'foreignField': '_id', 
            'as': 'post_likes.user_info'
        }
    }, {
        '$lookup': {
            'from': 'users_details', 
            'localField': 'post_comments.user_id', 
            'foreignField': '_id', 
            'as': 'post_comments.user_info'
        }
    }, {
        '$unwind': {
            'path': '$post_likes.user_info', 
            'preserveNullAndEmptyArrays': True
        }
    }, {
        '$unwind': {
            'path': '$post_comments.user_info', 
            'preserveNullAndEmptyArrays': True
        }
    }, {
        '$group': {
            '_id': '$_id', 
            'post_created_user_id': {
                '$first': '$post_created_user_id'
            }, 
            'post_content': {
                '$first': '$post_content'
            }, 
            'post_likes': {
                '$push': '$post_likes'
            }, 
            'post_comments': {
                '$push': '$post_comments'
            }
        }
    }
]
```

Getting the following output with duplicates val.

```
[{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "5f232c18a93ce29203b3f2f6"
  },
  "post_created_user_id": {
    "$oid": "5ed15463f43c335cb2e9ef73"
  },
  "post_content": "Content 1",
  "post_likes": [
    {
      "user_id": {
        "$oid": "5ed15463f43c335cb2e9ef75"
      },
      "user_info": {
        "_id": {
          "$oid": "5ed15463f43c335cb2e9ef75"
        },
        "first_name": "xxx3",
        "last_name": "xxx3",
        "email": "xxx3@gmail.com"
      }
    },
    {
      "user_id": {
        "$oid": "5ed15463f43c335cb2e9ef75"
      },
      "user_info": {
        "_id": {
          "$oid": "5ed15463f43c335cb2e9ef75"
        },
        "first_name": "xxx3",
        "last_name": "xxx3",
        "email": "xxx3@gmail.com"
      }
    },
    {
      "user_id": {
        "$oid": "5ed15463f43c335cb2e9ef76"
      },
      "user_info": {
        "_id": {
          "$oid": "5ed15463f43c335cb2e9ef76"
        },
        "first_name": "xxx4",
        "last_name": "xxx4",
        "email": "xxx4@gmail.com"
      }
    },
    {
      "user_id": {
        "$oid": "5ed15463f43c335cb2e9ef76"
      },
      "user_info": {
        "_id": {
          "$oid": "5ed15463f43c335cb2e9ef76"
        },
        "first_name": "xxx4",
        "last_name": "xxx4",
        "email": "xxx4@gmail.com"
      }
    }
  ],
  "post_comments": [
    {
      "comment_id": {
        "$oid": "5f2850966efb9d4e803b2030"
      },
      "user_id": {
        "$oid": "5ed15463f43c335cb2e9ef73"
      },
      "comment_content": "Test comment1",
      "comment_date": {
        "$date": "2020-08-03T17:59:50.132Z"
      },
      "user_info": {
        "_id": {
          "$oid": "5ed15463f43c335cb2e9ef73"
        },
        "first_name": "xxx1",
        "last_name": "xxx1",
        "email": "xxx@gmail.com"
      }
    },
    {
      "comment_id": {
        "$oid": "5f2850ff6efb9d4e803b2033"
      },
      "user_id": {
        "$oid": "5ed15463f43c335cb2e9ef74"
      },
      "comment_content": "test comments 1",
      "comment_date": {
        "$date": "2020-08-03T18:01:35.008Z"
      },
      "user_info": {
        "_id": {
          "$oid": "5ed15463f43c335cb2e9ef74"
        },
        "first_name": "xxx2",
        "last_name": "xxx2",
        "email": "xxx2@gmail.com"
      }
    },
    {
      "comment_id": {
        "$oid": "5f2850966efb9d4e803b2030"
      },
      "user_id": {
        "$oid": "5ed15463f43c335cb2e9ef73"
      },
      "comment_content": "Test comment1",
      "comment_date": {
        "$date": "2020-08-03T17:59:50.132Z"
      },
      "user_info": {
        "_id": {
          "$oid": "5ed15463f43c335cb2e9ef73"
        },
        "first_name": "xxx1",
        "last_name": "xxx1",
        "email": "xxx@gmail.com"
      }
    },
    {
      "comment_id": {
        "$oid": "5f2850ff6efb9d4e803b2033"
      },
      "user_id": {
        "$oid": "5ed15463f43c335cb2e9ef74"
      },
      "comment_content": "test comments 1",
      "comment_date": {
        "$date": "2020-08-03T18:01:35.008Z"
      },
      "user_info": {
        "_id": {
          "$oid": "5ed15463f43c335cb2e9ef74"
        },
        "first_name": "xxx2",
        "last_name": "xxx2",
        "email": "xxx2@gmail.com"
      }
    }
  ]
},{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "5f232c18a93ce29203b3f2f7"
  },
  "post_created_user_id": {
    "$oid": "5ed15463f43c335cb2e9ef73"
  },
  "post_content": "content 2",
  "post_likes": [
    {
      "user_id": {
        "$oid": "5ed15463f43c335cb2e9ef77"
      },
      "user_info": {
        "_id": {
          "$oid": "5ed15463f43c335cb2e9ef77"
        },
        "first_name": "xxx3",
        "last_name": "xxx3",
        "email": "xxx3@gmail.com"
      }
    },
    {
      "user_id": {
        "$oid": "5ed15463f43c335cb2e9ef77"
      },
      "user_info": {
        "_id": {
          "$oid": "5ed15463f43c335cb2e9ef77"
        },
        "first_name": "xxx3",
        "last_name": "xxx3",
        "email": "xxx3@gmail.com"
      }
    },
    {
      "user_id": {
        "$oid": "5ed15463f43c335cb2e9ef78"
      },
      "user_info": {
        "_id": {
          "$oid": "5ed15463f43c335cb2e9ef78"
        },
        "first_name": "xxx4",
        "last_name": "xxx4",
        "email": "xxx4@gmail.com"
      }
    },
    {
      "user_id": {
        "$oid": "5ed15463f43c335cb2e9ef78"
      },
      "user_info": {
        "_id": {
          "$oid": "5ed15463f43c335cb2e9ef78"
        },
        "first_name": "xxx4",
        "last_name": "xxx4",
        "email": "xxx4@gmail.com"
      }
    }
  ],
  "post_comments": [
    {
      "comment_id": {
        "$oid": "5f2850966efb9d4e803b2030"
      },
      "user_id": {
        "$oid": "5ed15463f43c335cb2e9ef73"
      },
      "comment_content": "Test comment1",
      "comment_date": {
        "$date": "2020-08-03T17:59:50.132Z"
      },
      "user_info": {
        "_id": {
          "$oid": "5ed15463f43c335cb2e9ef73"
        },
        "first_name": "xxx1",
        "last_name": "xxx1",
        "email": "xxx@gmail.com"
      }
    },
    {
      "comment_id": {
        "$oid": "5f2850ff6efb9d4e803b2033"
      },
      "user_id": {
        "$oid": "5ed15463f43c335cb2e9ef74"
      },
      "comment_content": "test comments 1",
      "comment_date": {
        "$date": "2020-08-03T18:01:35.008Z"
      },
      "user_info": {
        "_id": {
          "$oid": "5ed15463f43c335cb2e9ef74"
        },
        "first_name": "xxx2",
        "last_name": "xxx2",
        "email": "xxx2@gmail.com"
      }
    },
    {
      "comment_id": {
        "$oid": "5f2850966efb9d4e803b2030"
      },
      "user_id": {
        "$oid": "5ed15463f43c335cb2e9ef73"
      },
      "comment_content": "Test comment1",
      "comment_date": {
        "$date": "2020-08-03T17:59:50.132Z"
      },
      "user_info": {
        "_id": {
          "$oid": "5ed15463f43c335cb2e9ef73"
        },
        "first_name": "xxx1",
        "last_name": "xxx1",
        "email": "xxx@gmail.com"
      }
    },
    {
      "comment_id": {
        "$oid": "5f2850ff6efb9d4e803b2033"
      },
      "user_id": {
        "$oid": "5ed15463f43c335cb2e9ef74"
      },
      "comment_content": "test comments 1",
      "comment_date": {
        "$date": "2020-08-03T18:01:35.008Z"
      },
      "user_info": {
        "_id": {
          "$oid": "5ed15463f43c335cb2e9ef74"
        },
        "first_name": "xxx2",
        "last_name": "xxx2",
        "email": "xxx2@gmail.com"
      }
    }
  ]
}]
```

Can someone help me to construct the aggregation ?

Comment: this is my lookup query I used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look step by step,

#### post_comments lookup

- `$unwind` post_comments because its array and we need to lookup by single comment

```
db.posts.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$post_comments"
  },
```

- `$lookup` Its correct that you have prepared

```
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "users_details",
      localField: "post_comments.user_id",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "post_comments.user_info"
    }
  },
```

- removed not needed field from user_info

```
  {
    $project: {
      "post_comments.user_info._id": 0
    }
  },
```

- `$unwind` `post_comments.user_info` because its an array and we need only single user_info object

```
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$post_comments.user_info"
    }
  },
```

- `$group` by `_id` because above unwind separated the all documents, and we need to combine here

```
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      post_created_user_id: {
        $first: "$post_created_user_id"
      },
      post_date: {
        $first: "$post_date"
      },
      post_content: {
        $first: "$post_content"
      },
      post_comments: {
        $push: "$post_comments"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

#### post_likes lookup

- repeat the above steps just change `post_comments` to `post_likes` and change in $group to push `post_likes`, you can check the below playground.

You can combine the above query part as they are in sequence, separated for the explanation purpose.

Playground: https://mongoplayground.net/p/GzVvEbPNwkA

Comment: Thanks buddy. Its working. So I need to push all the field after unwiind using droup by. It is a great learning.

Comment: I have one more issue. In the post document I have post_like field which is also a reference field of User. When I do the aggregarion same whay for post_like , it is returing the same number of array that I have for post comment. example supose 3 users commented in the post and  different user like the post. in this situation how can I wrire the aggregation code ?

Comment: here is the ;link for it. https://mongoplayground.net/p/SGROpec1EON

Comment: so if I changed it to like_user_id , will it work ?

Comment: I was doing in wrong sequence. Thanks any way. is there any way to short the post_comments array by date ?

Comment: This is last time ok? i am tired, this is not the way to ask questions, you can ask separate question, for sort put `{$sort: {"post_comments.comment_date": 1}},` before first `$group`  1 for ascending and -1 for descending, you can approve the answer if its helpful.